# Strimzi - Connecting to External OpenShift Route Listener with SCRAM-SHA-512 Authentication with TLS with Sarama

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, strimzi, sarama

I have a Strimzi cluster setup with the follow yaml.

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  kafka:
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: route
        authentication:
          type: scram-sha-512
        tls: true
```

The pods come up fine and I've created a `KafkaUser` CR with SCRAM-512 like the following -

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: scram-user
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: kafka
spec:
  authentication:
    type: scram-sha-512
```

I've extracted the SCRAM password from the secret properly as well as gotten the `ca.crt` file from the cluster-ca-cert secret. I'm trying to follow the Go Sarama Code from this sample here - https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/master/examples/sasl_scram_client/main.go

I've also properly gotten the bootstrap server address from the OpenShift Route but I can't seem to connect.

```
go run sarama.go scram_client.go -brokers bootstrap-address:443  -username scram-user -passwd esoy2WksWRBp -topic test-topic -algorithm sha512 -tls true -ca /path/ca.crt
```

I've tried a few variations of the above command with adding `-certificate` or `-key` flags and none seem to work. Do I have the listener setup wrong?

edit - Forgot to include and mention it but this is what the error I get from the Go Sarama Code.

```
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 Failed to send SASL handshake kafka-broker:443: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 Closed connection to broker kafka-broker:443
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 client/metadata got error from broker -1 while fetching metadata: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 client/metadata no available broker to send metadata request to
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 client/brokers resurrecting 1 dead seed brokers
[Sarama] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 Closing Client
[Producer] 2021/08/18 09:22:36 failed to create producer:  kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
exit status 1
```

So it looks to be an cert issue but I seem to have followed the proper instructions to get the cert. My Kafka broker is just named kafka so the secret is just named kafka-cluster-ca-cert. The `ca.crt` file is the path I was providing to the Sarama code.

```
oc get secret kafka-cluster-ca-cert -o jsonpath='{.data.ca\.crt}' | base64 -d > ca.crt
```

Describe of the secret if it matters -

```
╰─ oc describe secret kafka-cluster-ca-cert
Name:         kafka-cluster-ca-cert
Namespace:    strimzi
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=kafka
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=strimzi-cluster-operator
              app.kubernetes.io/name=strimzi
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=strimzi-kafka
              strimzi.io/cluster=kafka
              strimzi.io/kind=Kafka
              strimzi.io/name=strimzi
Annotations:  strimzi.io/ca-cert-generation: 0

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
ca.crt:       1854 bytes
ca.p12:       1687 bytes
ca.password:  12 bytes
```

Comment: The listener configuration looks good. I have no experience with Sarama and SCRAM-SHA-512 ... your options look good from the linked Golang file, but I do not know if there are any otherthings you might need to do. What errors do you get from the client and form the brokers?

Comment: @Jakub hello Jakub. Apologies I added an edit with the Sarama error as well as the command to get the ca cert.

Comment: Another minor note - As a sanity check, I spun up a new Kafka cluster with the Route listener with tls: true and no SCRAM authentication and it connects fine using the usual steps by getting the crt from the kafka-cluster-ca-cert secret and etc. Not sure what exactly is the issue with SCRAM + TLS. Though instead of the Sarama Go Client I went with the confluent-go client since the previously linked Sarama client was expecting SASL username/password which were obviously missing this time around.

Comment: Last update - I figured out the issue and I've posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was mainly a command line issue. I kept trying to use the `-ca` flag when I should have just used only the `-certificate` flag. I also needed to add the `-verify` option flag as well. So the command that allowed me to produce was using the following -

```
go run sarama.go scram_client.go -brokers <your-kafka-boostrap-address>:443  -username <your-scram-username> -passwd <your-scram-password> -topic <your-topic> -algorithm sha512 -tls -certificate <full-path-to-your-cert-file>/ca.crt -verify true
```

And likewise the command to consume

```
go run sarama.go scram_client.go -brokers <your-kafka-boostrap-address>:443  -username <your-scram-username> -passwd <your-scram-password> -topic <your-topic> -mode consume -logmsg -algorithm sha512 -tls -certificate <full-path-to-your-cert-file>/ca.crt -verify true
```

Lesson learned I guess - understand the differences between CA, certificates, and keys.

Comment: Do you have any experiences in using sarama.go to access to AWS MSK? Many thanks.